# Gamma Matrices as nonstandard numbers, and Grassman Numbers

Tags: spinors, dirac-matrices, grassmann-numbers

I'm in the process of exploring the Dirac equation and its forms and consequences, and as such have just been initiated into the theory of spinors and their accompanying formalism.

One of the things I noticed early on was that the gamma matrices appearing in Dirac's equation are almost taking the form of a directional derivative, but with components that can't be expressed as real numbers. However, we don't necessarily need to represent these elements as matrices; we could also define some "nonstandard numbers" $\gamma^\mu$ with the usual anticommutation relation,

$$\left\lbrace\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu\right\rbrace=g^{\mu\nu}$$ 
in the same way that we can just define some $i$ s.t. $i^2=-1$, and indeed with a little playing around with the definitions you can show that the gamma matrices are just another representation of the quaternions.

Or in other words, it seems like you can think about $\partial\!\!\!/$ as a directional derivative in a bunch of nonstandard directions, and thus embed spinor-space in Minkowski space in a certain sense. I tried Googling around to see if anyone's done anything in that direction (pun not intended), but interestingly enough (from my perspective as a newcomer in the field), while there are indeed people talking about "fermionic directions," they use *Grassmann* numbers as their basis, not hypercomplex numbers like the quaternions.

Is there some deep insight as to why this is the case? I realize that this is mostly just a matter of notation, whether you view the gamma matrices as matrices operating on an independent spinor basis or as quaternions that operate on a Minkowski edition of $\mathbb{C}^4$, but as it does affect how I *understand* the material I still think it's worth asking the question.

Comment: You cannot satisfy all the requirements on the gammas simultaneously with just quaternions, they still need to be matrices

Comment: @Triatticus Hmm... You're right, you can't get $\gamma^0 \gamma^1=−\gamma^1 \gamma^0$ out of the quaternions since $1i=i1$. However, the point still stands -- it sure seems like the geometry of spin-space is better modeled by hypercomplex-ish numbers than Grassmann numbers, at least as far as the Dirac equation itself goes. Is there a place "later on" where that becomes untrue?

Comment: @linkhyrule5, the "nonstandard numbers" $\gamma^\mu$ can be considered as elements in the Clifford/Geometric algebra, without referencing any matrix. The "directional derivative in a bunch of nonstandard directions" $\not\partial$ is defined in Clifford/Geometric calculus. See wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_calculus

Comment: @MadMax Ah, that sounds closer to what I'm looking for. Let me take a look, thanks.

Comment: This link has a slight intro to the idea https://www.vttoth.com/CMS/physics-notes/165-quaternions-and-the-dirac-equation, indeed the author notes that the nice thing is that you reduce the number of dimensions of the matrices to $2\times 2$ matrices instead.